# How to extract symbols from Image?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am about to start learning CV and ML. I want to start by solving a problem. Below I am sharing an image and I want to extract each symbol and location from an image and create a new image with those extracted symbols in a pattern just like in source image. After that, I will do a translation job. Right now how can I or which steps I should follow to extract the symbols and find those symbols from the dataset (in terms of Gardiner's sign list) and place in the new image?
I know there is some computer vision + machine learning is involved in this process because symbols are not 100% accurate because these are too old symbols. I don't know from where to start and end. I have plans to use Python. Also, share if you know anyone already done this. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: size and orientation can be varied. the manual is not I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run sobel edge detection on source images in Gardiner's sign list.
2. Train a CNN on the list.
3. Normalize the contrast of the source image.
4. Run sobel edge detection on the source image. (referred to as source image heretofore)
5. Evaluate in the CNN by varying heights and widths(from the largest to smallest) on the source image.
6. Select the highest probability glyph. Output the corresponding Glyph from Gardiner's list at that start position and the corresponding height and width.

I do not claim this can be done in six simple steps, but this is the approach I would take.